# How to access the modalInstance $scope from outside the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-model

I want to update some value of a `$modal` in AngularJS but unable to understand how I can do this. Sample code is below:

```
var modalInstance;

  function setupCall(data) {

    var templateURL = 'partials/Chat.html';
    var cssClass =  'medium-Modal';
     modalInstance = $modal.open({
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false,
        backdropClick: false,
        windowClass: cssClass,
        templateUrl: templateURL,
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {


            $scope.updateStatus=function() {
            ...
            }
        }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function() {

    });
}
 // first time i call this function to open model
 setupCall(event);
```

Now when model open successfully and if I received some update from service and I again want to show updated values in a model then how I can call `updateStatus()` from outside the model. I try to using 
`modalInstance.updateStatus(..)` but it is not working. Can someone tell me a proper way to do this?

Comment: Why cant you inject the service inside this modal controller ?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are trying to do. If data is in service why isn't service binding update across whole app?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `scope` option to `$modal`, and then use AngularJS events

```
var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();

myService.doSomethingAsync(function (data) {
  $rootScope.$emit('some event', data);
});

$modal.open({
  scope: modalScope,
  controller: function ($scope) {

    /* ... */

    $scope.$on('some event', function() {
      $scope.updateStatus();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @lso Well i already think about to use $rootScope.$emit('') but it not looks a proper way. Is this possible to attach a custom event listener with model ?

Comment: Well yes, you can use any event listener you want. But note that `$rootScope.$emit` will only trigger listeners on the `$rootScope` (`$emit` goes upwards and `$rootScope` is the highest), so it’s not like it’s bloated or anything (as opposed to `$rootScope.$broadcast`, which will go down and through each and every scope)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$broadcast` to call that method. For example, after you received update from your service in your view's controller (where you are calling `setupCall` or launching the modal), do this:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("dataUpdatedFoo", {newData: "bar"));
```

Now, inside your controller of modal, register a listener for this:

```
$scope.$on("dataUpdatedFoo", function(e, data) {
    $scope.updateStatus();
});
```

Comment: For broadcast to work properly, modal controller should be activated at the point. In this case it wont work

Comment: I just updated the answer by broadcasting via `$rootScope`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I resolve this by adding custom eventlistener.

```
 var listeners = [];

function _addEventListener(listener) {
    listeners.push(listener);
    return listener;
}

function _removeListener(listener) {
    for (var i=0; i < listeners.length; i++){
        if (listeners[i] === listener){
            listeners.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
} 
function setupCall(data) {
   ......
    modalInstance = $modal.open({
        backdrop: "static",
        keyboard: false,
        backdropClick: false,
        windowClass: cssClass,
        templateUrl: templateURL,
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

            var listener = _addEventListener(function (event) {
              $log.info("chat msg: "+JSON.stringify(event));
            });

            $scope.$on('destroy', function () {
                _removeListener(listener)
            });
            ...
```